# How to access the internet from a virtual machine in Gnome Boxes?

Tags: networking, virtualization, gnome-boxes

I installed [Gnome Boxes](https://live.gnome.org/Design/Apps/Boxes), created a new virtual machine and booted an ISO. The ISO boots up fine and the network inside the virtual machine got automatically configured by the distro (with *dhcpd*):

- **IP** `enp0s3` got the IP `10.0.2.15`
- **DNS** nameserver: `10.0.2.3`
- **Gateway** default: `10.0.2.2`

Both other hosts are up and I can ping all IPs. DNS works too. But I can't ping anything not on the local net.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to a user in the [german Arch-Linux board](https://bbs.archlinux.de/) I got an answer: **Boxes** uses NAT for the host, and some protocols (like *ICMP*) aren't working. So I couldn't use `ping`, `tracepath` and the like, but the network and an installation works nevertheless.

Comment: Are you able to ssh onto the virtual machine from your host? I can't. What connection type are you using?

Comment: @jedi Sorry, I can't remember if that worked (question was asked over 4 years ago). I assume that it worked (in the local net at least), cause the box provided some deamons. I don't have Boxes installed anymore, maybe someone else can provide an answer.